# IIS won't cache large (76MB) file

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis, iis-8.5

I can't seem to get IIS on Windows 2012 R2 to cache a large .exe file. That is, when I constantly request the file I see the file being read constantly in in Resource Monitor, and running

```
netsh http show cachestate
```

does not show the file cached.

I think I've configured the system to cache .exe files for the folder in the kernel and to not have a max file size. The total cache size limit is 0, which I understand will make the system use up to half of all memory. The server has 6 GB of RAM, with lots of it free.

That is, in the Output Cache settings for the root of the web server:

- Maximum cached response size (in bytes) = 0 (also reflected in applicationHost.config's maxResponseSize value)
- Cache size limit (in MB) is not checked (also in applicationHost.config maxCacheSize = 0)
- Enable cache and Enable kernel cache are checked (both set to true in applicationHost.config

I'm serving the file from a virtual folder configured to be a 4.0 ASP.NET application. 4.6.2 is installed. The virtual folder points to a UNC share that is on the same system. (I know I could point to the local file system; I'm simulating hosting files that are on another system.)

The web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <clear />
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    <caching>
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".txt" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
        <add extension=".exe" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
      </profiles>
    </caching>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It will cache small .txt and .exe files (about 20 bytes each).

What am I missing that's preventing IIS from caching the large file?

Comment: I've tried pointing to the local file system instead of the UNC share that's on the system, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Testing with different file sizes, it will cache a 256000 byte file but not a 300000 byte file. It feels like there's another limit that defaults to 256KB that I haven't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per the registry(UriMaxUriBytes ) which controls  size of file
>   which can be cached on the kernel is 16 MB.Also there are many
>   scenarios in which http.sys will not cache the content.Please check
>   this [KB article
>   instances-in-which-http-sys-does-not-cache-content](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/817445/instances-in-which-http-sys-does-not-cache-content)

To get it working - create the following DWORD values under the following registry key:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters**

- UriMaxUriBytes -UriMaxUriBytes  262144 (bytes)  4096(4k) – 16777216(16MB) bytes
  Any response that is greater than this value is not cached in the kernel response cache.    1
  3
- UriScavengerPeriod -Determines the frequency of the cache scavenger. Any response or fragment that has not been accessed in the number of seconds equal to UriScavengerPeriod is flushed.

You can also tweak UriMaxCacheMegabyteCount (specifies the maximum memory that is available to the kernel-mode cache.) which is by default zero for http.sys to decide but you can give a high value

so you can

1. set
   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\UriMaxUriBytes
   to 16777216**
2. check from non UNC directory where a file less than 16 MB
3. No authentication for this request or No dynamic compression enabled for this mime type

more details can be found on this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364670(v=vs.85).aspx) and [server performance tuning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn567678(v=vs.85).aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think I've been running into that 16MB limit. There are only a few places on the web that even mention it. This suggests that I should look into user mode caching.

Comment: Setting MaxCachedFileSize  to a large value (e.g. 256MB) in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Inetinfo\Parameters and recycling w3wp worked.